# How to change the position of words in sentence by using recursion in C?

Tags: c, string, recursion, substring

How to make ABC DEF GHI to GHI DEF ABC by using recursive function?

```
void reverse(char *str)
{
    if (*str)
    {
        if(str != ' ')
        {
            str += 1;
        }
        reverse(str+1);
        printf("%c", str);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why recursion ?

Comment: trying to use this method

Comment: Does the above code not work?  Does it produce any warnings or errors? What exactly are you having difficulty with?

Comment: Note: ```The values returned are nonzero if the character c falls into the tested class, and a zero value if not.```.  Non-zero doesn't necessarily mean ```1```.

Comment: Note: ```&& operator:

If the left operand and the right operand are both different than 0 it evaluates to 1 otherwise it evaluates to 0.

If the left operand is 0, the right operand is not evaluated and the result is 0.```

Comment: the code can't work. no warning. i think my code make sense...but didn't have output.

Comment: Before reaching ```printf```, ```reverse``` calls itself, making a new stack frame, and then repeats the cycle until ```*str != 0```, in which case it exits. So ```printf``` never gets executed.

Comment: Aside: ```%s``` is for a string, not a ```%c```.

Comment: The question is misleading. The reverse of ```ABC DEF``` is not ```DEF ABC```.

Comment: `if(str != ' ')` should have given you a warning, since you're comparing a pointer to an integer.  You probably wanted `if(*str != ' ')` instead.  Similarly, `printf("%c", str);` should also have given you a warning, since you're trying to format a pointer as a character value, which obviously won't work.

Comment: Is `If(str ! = ' ')` to skip whitespaces? If so, use `while(str == ' ')` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`printf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) specifier `%s` can be used with a *precision* of `*`, which allows you to pass an integer value (as an `int`) specifying the maximum number of bytes to read from the string.

[`strspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strspn) and [`strcspn`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn) can be used to find *spans* in strings, consisting of characters found or not found in their second argument, respectively.

Used together, these functions allow us to skip over leading whitespace, and find the length of each substring delimited by whitespace.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void print_sentence_backwards(const char *sent)
{
    sent += strspn(sent, " ");    
    
    if (*sent) {
        size_t n = strcspn(sent, " "); 
        print_sentence_backwards(sent + n);
        printf("%.*s ", (int) n, sent);
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    print_sentence_backwards("ABC DEF GHI");
    putchar('\n');
}
```

```
GHI DEF ABC
```